# How to add an extra y-axis label in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to add an additional axis label on the right side of an axis, but don't want ticks nor tick labels.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,2,sharey=True,sharex=True)
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        pd.Series(np.random.random(10)).plot(ax=axs[i,j])
        axs[0,j].set_title('j = {}'.format(j))
    ax[1,j].set_ylabel('x')
    secaxy = axs[i,1].secondary_yaxis('right')
    secaxy.set_ylabel('i = {}'.format(i))
    secaxy.set_yticks([])
    ax[i,0].set_ylabel('y')
```

For some reason the `set_yticks([])` doesn't replace the ticks.

```py
[In]: secaxy.get_yticks()
[Out:] array([-0.25,  0.  ,  0.25,  0.5 ,  0.75,  1.  ,  1.25])
```

What would be a convenient way to get an additional axis label on the right side of the plot without ticks?

[image: correct labels, but need to remove the ticks on the right]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't misuse a secondary axes for that. Just put the label to the right and turn it visible.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,2,sharey=True,sharex=True) 
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        pd.Series(np.random.random(10)).plot(ax=axs[i,j])
for j in range(2):
    axs[0,j].set_title('j = {}'.format(j))
for i in range(2):
    axs[i,1].set_ylabel('i = {}'.format(i))
    axs[i,1].yaxis.get_label().set_visible(True)
    axs[i,1].yaxis.set_label_position("right")
    axs[i,0].set_ylabel('y')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I need to put an additional label on the right side. I have a label also for the left side. I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem. For the left side adding `axs[i,0].set_ylabel('y')` would work? I updated the answer accordingly.